# Storing SVG objects in an array for loading

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

I am having some trouble with using the function `Element.append(el)` in the Snap.svg API. I need to store an instance of that SVG in an array of variables so that I can access specific ones throughout runtime.

When I try this code with just storing it into `groupViews`, it works. But, putting it an array (`groupView`) brings me this error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read proerty 'append' of undefined`

The console shows me the same output when I log `groupViews` and `groupView[i]` so I am not sure what else to try.

Any ideas as to how I can solve this? Thanks.

```
for(var i = 0; i < numOfGroups; i++)
  {
    var sel = '#GroupView' + i;
    groupView[i] = Snap(sel);
    console.log(groupView[i]);
    groupViews = Snap('#GroupView0');
    console.log(groupViews);


    Snap.load("/svg/groupView-12_13_2016-01.svg", function(f) {
      groupView[i].append(f);
      groupViews.append(f);


    }); //end of Snap.load(groupView)


  }
```

Edit (1/5):

Here is the HTML code where I have empty SVGs loaded:

```
<div class = "groupView0">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 3640.9 540.5' id='GroupView0'></svg>
</div>

<div class = "groupView1">
    <svg viewBox='0 0 3640.9 540.5' id='GroupView1'></svg>
</div>
```

Hence, this is why I am loading the specific SVG file and appending it in JS. Is there a better way to do this?

Edit (1/6):

Here is a small portion of my svg file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 20.0.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     viewBox="0 0 3640.9 540.5" style="enable-background:new 0 0 3640.9 540.5;" xml:space="preserve">

<g id="A" onclick="detailedView();" cursor="pointer">
    <rect id="PanelBackground" x="35.4" y="55.5" class="st2" width="173.2" height="155"/> <!--height="444" -->
    <g id="UpperBar">
        <linearGradient id="Header_20_" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse" x1="35.3937" y1="67.0279" x2="208.5774" y2="67.0279">
            <stop  offset="0" style="stop-color:#F68E1E"/>
            <stop  offset="0.5" style="stop-color:#F16A22"/>
            <stop  offset="0.903" style="stop-color:#F05F22"/>
            <stop  offset="1" style="stop-color:#F05C22"/>
        </linearGradient>
        <polygon id="Header" class="st3" points="35.4,55.5 208.6,55.5 208.6,78.6 35.4,78.6      "/>
        <g>
            <rect x="82.1" y="61.8" class="st4" width="121" height="10.8"/>
            <text id="GroupName" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 82.0885 71.6627)" class="st5 st6 st7">A</text>
            <text id="FloorNumber" transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 182.3287 141.8773)" class="st2 st19 st7">X</text>
        </g>
     </g>
</svg>
```

After executing the code you posted.. 
If I try to run code like:

```
groupName[0] = groupView[0].select('#GroupName');
groupName[0].attr({
    text: "something"
});
```

I get this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Comment: Is the svg already loaded? Or are you just loading it at Snap.load?

Comment: @MiltoxBeyond Yep, the SVG is loaded in my HTML page.

Comment: What are you trying to do, store svg elements to be added later ? Or store SVG elements whilst adding some or all of the elements to the DOM at the same time, so they are all in the DOM and displayed, but you just access them later ? It probably doesn't make sense to append(f) twice, but a bit more info is needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this, it uses clone() as it looks like you are loading in the same SVG file each time, so we could load it in once, then clone() it to save repeated calls to the server.

This relies on the basis that the svg file will have an outer  markup in it. If it's partial svg, and only has a  element, change the select('svg') to select('group') or whatever it is.

Then we store a reference to the clone, and then append that element to the indexed svg element.

Here is a full example, the svg test.svg loaded in is simply..

```
<svg>
  <rect x="20" y="20" width="100" height="100" />
</svg>
```

Main html/js

```
<body>
<div class="groupView0">
  <svg id="groupView0"></svg>
</div>
<div class="groupView1">
  <svg id="groupView1"></svg>
</div>
<div class="groupView2">
  <svg id="groupView2"></svg>
</div>

<script>

var sel = "#groupView";
var groupView = [];
var numOfGroups = 3;

Snap.load("test.svg",onSVGLoaded);

function onSVGLoaded ( fragment ) {
  groupView[0] = Snap( sel + '0' ).append( fragment ).select('svg');

  for( var i = 1; i < numOfGroups; i++ ) {
    groupView[i] = groupView[0].clone().appendTo( Snap( sel + i ) );
  } 

  groupView[0].attr({ fill: 'yellow' });
  groupView[1].attr({ fill: 'red' });
  groupView[2].attr({ fill: 'green' });
}
```

[Working example](http://svg.dabbles.info/test/testload.html)

Comment: Hi Ian, I edited my post regarding whats already in the DOM. I need that array so I can reference each specific instance of the SVG I am loading so that I can use functions like Element.animate or Element.attr for each instance.

Comment: Is it the same svg that will be loaded into each groupview, or are there lots of different svgs ? It's not clear whats in the svg file you are loading.

Comment: It is the same svg that I am loading. I just need multiple instances of that svg to correlate with data on the back-end. The svg file contains multiple elements that all correlate to variables on the back-end.

Comment: I've just done an update to my answer which may be more suited

Comment: Am I supposed to replace `<CSSSelectorForChildElement>` with something? I am not sure what is going on there.

Comment: It depends on what is in your SVG file groupView-12_13_2016-01.svg as you haven't shown that, it's hard to know. For example, if inside your file, its an <svg>...</svg>, you could just have select('svg'), if it's <g></g> then select('g'), or whatever the outermost element is or the one you want to add. Maybe include the svg markup in the question if its not too big (or similar minimal example otherwise).

Comment: I have updated the answer with a working live example, and removed the need for a css selector (assuming you are happy to add the whole SVG elements each time).

Comment: Ian, thanks for the live example. It does properly load three instances of the specific svg but there is still an issue when I try to select an element within `groupView[i]`. I need to be able to select a text element for example and change it. Ill add a small portion of my svg file to my question to make it clear.

Comment: Ian, please disregard my last comment. I made a silly mistake with variable declaration that I fixed. Your answer has basically solved my problem and I now have a solution to move forward with. Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Yes, you can still do a select or selectAll from the groupView, eg groupView[1].select('text').animate( ... )

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using an asynchronous function inside of the loop, so the file doesn't load until after it has finished (especially since you call the same file `numOfGroups - 1` times. Basically when the result does return, i has already processed the entire array and the value of i is no longer in the range you expect it to be (`numOfGroups` to be exact).

Since `groupView[numOfGroups]` was never set to a value it is undefined.

The ideal solution is to either wait for the external file to load before looping (in the callback function) like so:

```
var sel = '#GroupView';
var groupView = [];
Snap.load("/svg/groupView-12_13_2016-01.svg", function(f) {
      for(var i = 0; i < numOfGroups; i++) {
          groupView[i] = new Snap(sel+i);
          groupView[i].append(f);
      }      
});
```

Or to define a variable within the loop scope to trick the callback function into using a scope variable when assigning the value of the load, again like so:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numOfGroups; i++)
  {
    var sel = '#GroupView' + i;
    var cur = i; //This creates a scope variable for the current callback.
    groupView[i] = Snap(sel);
    console.log(groupView[i]);
    groupViews = Snap('#GroupView0');
    console.log(groupViews);


    Snap.load("/svg/groupView-12_13_2016-01.svg", function(f) {
      groupView[cur].append(f);
      groupViews.append(f);


    }); //end of Snap.load(groupView)
  }
```

However, the second solution actually is very inefficient considering it makes requests `numOfGroups` of times for the same file, and loads `numOfGroups` callbacks into memory. The only time it should be necessary is if you are actually going to call different files.

Finally I'll give you a simple example of what is happening.

```js
var d = document.getElementById("testOutput");
var b = document.getElementById("trigger");

function RunTest() {
  var arr = [];
  d.innerHTML = "";
  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    d.innerHTML += "Loop: " + i;
    arr[i] = i;
    setTimeout(function() {
      d.innerHTML += "i is " + i + "<br />";
    }, 1000); //Simulates Delay while loading...
    d.innerHTML += "...Finished Loop </br>";
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="trigger" type="button" onClick="RunTest()" value="Test" />
<div id="testOutput"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the in depth explanation and example of what is occurring in my code. I tried both solutions you provided though and I still run into an issue. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined`

Comment: I don't think your 2nd example doesn't creates scope ? It's also unclear about having 2 appends, but that's down to more clarity needed in the original question.

Comment: The first example is not the complete code.  you have to set `groupView = [];`

Comment: Yes @Ian I just left it so the original author would do whatever he wanted with it...